# How does this let clause work?

Tags: haskell, functional-programming

I'm a beginner to Haskell, and I don't understand how this code snippet works. I don't understand what happens in the 'let' declaration, what does (ls1,ls2) get after the 'split xys' is called?

```
split :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
split [] = ([], [])
split ((x, y):xys) = let (ls1, ls2) = split xys
                     in
                     (x:ls1, y:ls2)
```

Let's use a short example, to explain the first recursion iteration:

If this is the call: `split [(1,2),(3,4)]` what does `split xys` returns in the first iteration? and what goes to (ls1, ls2) because of the 'let'?

Comment: Split returns a tuple, the let binds variable to elements of a tuple thanks to pattern matching.

Comment: Is it the recursion that is confusing you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
split :: [(a, b)] -> ([a], [b])
```

`split` is a function that takes in a list of pairs, and returns a pair of lists. It is defined using recursion:

```
split [] = ([], [])
```

Splitting the empty list results in two empty lists.

```
split ((x, y):xys) =
```

This equation defines how to split a list with at least one element in it, by pattern matching.  The two parts of the first pair in the list will be called `x` and `y`, and the rest of the list---whatever is left after the first pair---will be called `xys`.

```
                    let (ls1, ls2) = split xys
```

This clause will be defined in terms of a *recursive call*.  We take the list without the first pair in it, and call `split` on that, which, remember, will return a pair of two lists.  We use pattern-matching again, so `ls1` and `ls2` will be those two lists.

```
                    in (x:ls1, y:ls2)
```

We will return a new pair of lists, as we must. The first list will consist of the first list from the recursive call, plus the first part of the pair that we cut off before recursing.  The second list will similarly consist of the second list from the recursive call, plus the second part of the pair that we cut off before recursing.

**Examples:**

`split [(1,2),(3,4)]`: This isn't splitting the empty list, so the second equation matches. `x` is bound to `1`, `y` is bound to `2`, and `xys` is bound to `[(3, 4)]`.  We recursively call split on `[(3, 4)]`.  In this recursive execution, `x` is `3`, `y` is `4`, and `xys` is `[]`.  We recursively call `split` again, and this time the base case is matched and it returns `([], [])`.  In the first recursive call, this means that `ls1` is bound to `[]` and `ls2` is bound to `[]`.  So `x:ls1` is `[3]` and `y:ls2` is `[4]`, so this recursive call returns `([3],[4])`.  The original call gets this result, so `ls1` is bound to the first component of this pair, `[3]`, and `ls2` to the second, `[4]`.  Thus `x:ls1` is `[1, 3]` and `y:ls2` is `[2, 4]`. The top-level call therefore returns `([1, 3], [2, 4])`.